# How can I import a single column of data into Excel from tab-delimited text file?

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, import, data-import

Each of my tab delimited text files has 1 column of data I want (well 2, but baby steps). I want to select the file to import, have that 1 column of data paste into my spreadsheet (into the cell I select, since automating that is too tricky), and then repeat.

After about 40 iterations, this is where I'm at. It keeps importing the entire file, and telling me the column MG/ML is not found.

```
Sub ImportMGMLColumn()
' Define variables
Dim filePath As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fileDialog As fileDialog
Dim headerCell As Range
Dim lastColumn As Long

' Set up file dialog
Set fileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fileDialog.Title = "Select the Tab-Separated Text File"

' Allow the user to select only one file
fileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False

' Show the file dialog and get the selected file path
If fileDialog.Show = -1 Then
    filePath = fileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    ' User canceled the file selection
    Exit Sub
End If

' Set the worksheet where you want to import the data
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name

' Clear existing data in the target column (excluding the header)
ws.Range("A:B").ClearContents ' Change the range as needed

' Import data from the selected text file
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & filePath, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .Refresh
End With

' Find the header cell with "MG/ML"
On Error Resume Next
Set headerCell = ws.Rows(1).Find("MG/ML", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
On Error GoTo 0

' If "MG/ML" header is found, copy and paste only the desired column
If Not headerCell Is Nothing Then
    lastColumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ws.Columns(headerCell.Column).Copy ws.Columns(lastColumn + 1) ' Paste next to the last column
Else
    ' Notify if "MG/ML" header is not found
    MsgBox "Column 'MG/ML' not found in the imported data.", vbExclamation
End If

' Clear clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you write in two different ways the string to  be found, you probably must also add `MatchCase:=False` in `ws.Rows(1).Find("MG/ML", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)`. No need to place `Set headerCell =` between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`.Then, I cannot understand anything from your explanation related to  what is needed next. I would suggest you to edit the question and place two pictures. One showing existing (after  `QueryTables`) and another (others) showing the desired result(s).

Comment: There are 2 ways for the string to be found? I only have the one reference to find "MG/ML", then what to do if it's found. I believe you, but what is the 2nd? I'm also confused; you said I probably need to add matchcase :=False, but then in the next sentence, that I don't need Set headerCell =, which precedes the code you told me to modify. At first I thought you meant I could just delete ONLY Set headerCell = and leave the rest of the line, but if I do that, the code breaks. When I just add the matchCase :=false part, I still get the error that the MG/ML cannot be found.

Comment: If you did not show (at least) a picture with your data, we can only suggest what we supposed to be of some help. I **did not talk about 2 ways** (even there is another way). I suggested that you may need `MatchCase:=False`, as another `Optional` parameter accepted by `Find` method. If it still does not match anything you should check if the header is **really** on the first row, or the respective header **does not contain only "MG/ML"**. It maybe is "MG/ML    ". I mean, having spaces as prefix or suffix. Then, I told you that `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` are not necessary.

Comment: You can simple comment or delete the two mentioned code lines. Now, **is it so difficult to help us helping you**? I mean, to edit the question and show us eloquent pictures of existing situation and desired one?

Comment: I pasted screenshots of an example data file. I appreciate any help.